# Losing keyboard and mouse events in swing application

Tags: java, swing, events

I am participting in development of a Swing application that has a very complex class structure due to supporting different graphic styles.
There are a few cases where mouse and keyboard events disappear *somewhere* in the window chain.
I tried finding them by adding logging to every Listener class I could find, but still, I dont know where they are being caught and processed (or lost).
Coming from Win32 and SWT development, I would simply start Winspector Spy and find this out by tracking through the native widgets. But this is not possbile in Swing.

What can I do?
Is there something like Winspector which works for Swing applications?
Or is there a central point in a swing application where I can add debugging and figure out where the events go?

Comment: A KeyEvent is only dispatched to the component with focus. Don't use a KeyListener, it is not reliable as you have noticed. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. With Key Bindings you can have key events even if the component doesn't have focus. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and examples.

Comment: That will help a lot thank you - about the general understanding of which events go where - my guess is there is no tool I could use to help with questions like this?

Comment: *about the general understanding of which events go where* - not really sure you need to know that. If you design the application properly that is a low level detail you don't need to worry about.  Check out [Global Event Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/). The AWTEventListener will allow you to listen to events. You can get the source of the event.

Comment: This is code thats in part 10 years old - I am trying to refactor this in order to get it more usable. thank you for the pointer, this is super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @camickr suggested in the comment about using the global event listener described
[in this article](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/)
did assist greatly in figuring out the UI hierarchy of that old project.